# Share Dialog vs Share Button - noticeable differences

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-sharer

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog VS https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button

In experimenting with both the FB.ui share dialog and using the fb:share-button / class="fb-share-button" I've noticed that using the FB.ui method does not offer sharing options (Share on your timeline, friends' timeline, etc) in the dialog and the og:description is not displayed on the FB post (yet it is in the post preview) and markup formatting for the display is different. It's obvious that both methods are using two different services:

FB.ui: .../v2.0/dialog/share... and Share Button: .../sharer/sharer.php?...

One would think that by leveraging the JavaScript SDK a developer would have more options to customize the sharing experience, but in my experience thus far, that doesn't seem to be case.

Yes, I've run my links through the linter, my open graph tags are set properly and I've added the "scrape=true" to my query string.

At the very least, I'd hope that the og:description would get displayed on a FB post by leveraging the SDK and that the formatting would be the same. Any validation of this behavior and workarounds?

Comment: Is this in your localhost environment? If you, it doesn't work. Just a small piece of information that might be helpfull.

Comment: Thanks for the info, Doc, but this work is Internet facing, scrapable by the FB linter and as I mentioned works as expected using the Share Btn, but not through the Share Dialong (FB.ui)

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here; plus the share count on the url is not updated if shared with the share dialog; it is if it's done using the share button.

pretty weird, a bug maybe?

Comment: Thanks for the validation! I'm going to post this on the FB Developers page to see if this issue can get some answers / validation / traction there.